# Paparazzi but online (web capture tool needed)

Tags: image-capture

I'm needing a webservice for capturing and entire website and export it to JPG or PNG.

I'm using Paparazzi on my mac, but I've a linux server and would like to that on linux.

Any idea? Do you know any webservice?

Answer (score 2):

http://browsershots.org/

Is this the kind of capture you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

On linux I use [screengrab for firefox](http://www.screengrab.org/).

Online you should try http://browsershots.org, it provides shots from many different browsers, I use it when I have to test the appearance of a page on different web browsers.